# the settings for my extensions on vs code all display one json file which is the public one for vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[vs code extension json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKDn5.png)

I am trying to edit the settings of some of my extensions like the live sass compiler but when I go to the settings of the extension all I get is a JSON file about the vscode setting itself but not the extension settings I wonder how can I solve that.

whenever I try to reach the setting of ...any... extension--> this is all I get:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Pro (Filter Machine)",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "vscode-edge-devtools.mirrorEdits": true,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.showOutputWindow": false
}
```

Comment: can you give an example, I have no clue what you mean, all settings are always defined in a json file, the GUI is just there for easy manipulation of simple types

Comment: hi , @rioV8 i have added the code that appears to me

Comment: the extension settings are stored in this JSON file, using names like `tabnine.experimentalAutoImports`, use the settings GUI `Ctrl+,` to see what you can change